# AngularJS - 'DashboardController' Not Registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a new angular app and I can't figure out why my controller is not registering. The full error I get is:

> The controller with the name 'DashboardController' is not registered.

I have the app module and dashboard controller in two separate files:

app.js:

```
var HtJobPortal = (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('HtJobPortal', []);
})();
```

DashboardController:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    HtJobPortal.controller('DashboardController', []);

    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'DashboardController';

})();
```

And my HTML is just attempting to extract the title:

```
<body ng-controller="DashboardController">
    {{title}}


    <!-- JS Scripts -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <!-- Application Directive -->
    <script src="Scripts/controllers/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="Scripts/controllers/DashboardController.js"></script>

</body>
```

Can anybody help point out what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to add the IIFE function assign to a variable just remove it. The whole point of using IIFe is to reduce the time of the variable life. making a global variable just make the lifetime much longer

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('HtJobPortal', []);
})();
```

in the controller, file add the module reference to the controller and create a function to that controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
 angular.module('HtJobPortal')
    .controller('DashboardController',DashboardController);

    DashboardController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function DashboardController($scope){      
       var vm = this;
       vm.title = 'DashboardController';
    }

})();
```

In the html add the `ng-app` directive also. since you are using the controlleras , use the correct syntaxes.

```
<body ng-app="HtJobPortal" ng-controller="DashboardController as vm">
    {{vm.title}}


    <!-- JS Scripts -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <!-- Application Directive -->
    <script src="Scripts/controllers/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="Scripts/controllers/DashboardController.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Stops the errors but doesn't output the title - just a blank screen

Comment: @Web Develop Wolf no problem bro :D